# Jenkins remote ssh connection failed with "unsupported public key algorithm"

Tags: git, jenkins, ssh, cicd

When I try connecting from Jenkins UI to remote server through SSH plugin.
[image]

It fails with errors. The following logs are from the remote server.

> userauth_pubkey: unsupported public key algorithm:
> rsa-sha2-512[preauth]
>
> userauth_pubkey: unsupported public key algorithm:rsa-sha2-256
> [preauth]

However, when I try connecting through cli from the server where jenkins is installed. It works.

I changed the config files at **/etc/ssh/sshd_config** and **/etc/ssh/ssh_config**
by adding the line **PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes +ssh-rsa**

Here are the details of my jenkins server and jenkins

Server Details :
Amazon Linux, Fedora 23

Jenkins Details :
Jenkins Version : 2.401.1
SSH Plugin Version : 2.6.1

Can someone help me connect to my remote server. So that I can create a pipeline to build and execute pull branch on remote servers